# Not authorized on test to execute command

Tags: mongodb, connectivity, javascript

Here is my code:

```
mongoose.connect(consts.database, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    sslCA: consts.databaseCert,
});
//...
const user = await db.userModel.findOne({
    username: usernameLowerCase
}).exec();
```

Here is my DB connection string (anonymized):

```
mongodb://myUser:userPW@SG-staging-111.servers.mongodirector.com:27017,SG-staging-43334.servers.mongodirector.com:27017?replicaSet=RS-staging-0&ssl=true&authSource=stagingDB
```

I'm getting this error:

```
MongoError: not authorized on test to execute command {
    find: "users",
    filter: {
        username: "bob"
    },
    projection: {},
    limit: 1,
    singleBatch: true,
    batchSize: 1,
    returnKey: false,
    showRecordId: false,
    lsid: {
        id: UUID("0a9400e3-83e3-429c-b8c9-92ade2ff210e")
    },
    $clusterTime: {
        clusterTime: Timestamp(1613200171, 1),
        signature: {
            hash: BinData(0, FED473B580D13E7E5073756DB5140981AADB2985),
            keyId: 6928615819992774977
        }
    },
    $db: "test"
}
```

DB user's info:

```
myUser  [{"role":"readWrite","db":"stagingDB"}]
```

I have no clue why I am getting this error `not authorized on test to execute command`, and in the return string `$db: "test"` I don't even have a database named `test`. What could I be doing wrong? I just recently added this new user `myUser`, but now I'm getting this error. Does this error mean that the user is not authorized to "test" commands? Or, does it mean that I am trying to (somehow) connect with a DB named "test"?

Comment: Database `test` is the default database when you don't specify any. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63754742/authentication-failure-while-trying-to-save-to-mongodb/63755470#63755470

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out that I was missing a `/authDBName` in my connection string. It should be this:

```
mongodb://myUser:userPW@SG-staging-111.servers.mongodirector.com:27017,SG-staging-43334.servers.mongodirector.com:27017/stagingDB?replicaSet=RS-staging-0&ssl=true&authSource=stagingDB
```